# NSDateFormatter different base year iOS 5 and iOS 6 parsing the day of the year

Tags: ios5, ios6, nsdateformatter

I'm working with calendars and found a problem with NSDateFormatter that behaves different on iOS 5.0 and iOS 6.0.
I try to create dates for certain days of the year.
So for example I would like to know which is the 59'th day of the year.

To achieve this I use a NSDateFormatter and set it's date format to "DDD" (three digits day of the year) and simply try to parse the string containing the day.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// just gettting rid of the timezone
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"DDD"];

NSMutableString *outPutString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"\n"];
for (int i = 1; i <= 366; i++)
{
    NSString *dayOfTheYearString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
    [outPutString appendFormat:@"%3i: %@ string:(%@)\n", i, [formatter dateFromString:dayOfTheYearString], dayOfTheYearString];
}

NSLog(@"%@", outPutString);
[formatter release];
```

Running this on iOS 5.0 Simulator works fine. the console prints:

```
001: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 string:(1)
002: 1970-01-02 00:00:00 +0000 string:(2)
003: 1970-01-03 00:00:00 +0000 string:(3)
004: 1970-01-04 00:00:00 +0000 string:(4)
005: 1970-01-05 00:00:00 +0000 string:(5)
[...]
058: 1970-02-27 00:00:00 +0000 string:(58)
059: 1970-02-28 00:00:00 +0000 string:(59)
060: 1970-03-01 00:00:00 +0000 string:(60)
061: 1970-03-02 00:00:00 +0000 string:(61)
[...]
```

But on iOS 6.0 the console prints:

```
001: 2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 string:(1)
002: 2000-01-02 00:00:00 +0000 string:(2)
003: 2000-01-03 00:00:00 +0000 string:(3)
004: 2000-01-04 00:00:00 +0000 string:(4)
005: 2000-01-05 00:00:00 +0000 string:(5)
[...]
058: 2000-02-27 00:00:00 +0000 string:(58)
059: 2000-02-28 00:00:00 +0000 string:(59)
060: 2000-02-29 00:00:00 +0000 string:(60)
061: 2000-03-01 00:00:00 +0000 string:(61)
[...]
```

And this is my main problem. Since year 2000 is a leap year the results of my following calculations differ between iOS 5.0 and iOS 6.0.

I know that it is necessary to be aware of the year being a leap year or not when asking for the x'th day. But if I don't deliver any information about the year I expect the resulting date being in 1970!

So how to force the NSDateFormatter to create (worldwide standard used) dates in year 1970 when not else mentioned in iOS 6.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the base year when you pass in the date. Instead of using

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"DDD"];
```

use

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-DDD"];
```

Then, change your day of year string to

```
NSString *dayOfTheYearString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1970-%i", i];
```